# Problems with geom_text and pausing the animation

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm trying to replicate the following code ([thomasp85/gganimate](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/wiki/Temperature-time-series)). I have two problems:

1. I don't want to show the labels (variable: partidos) of the first `geom_point`;
2. I would like that once the animation ends, for a few seconds the labels (variable: partidos) of the last `geom_point` are shown.

```
    dput(polls_)
structure(list(week = structure(c(1551571200, 1551571200, 1551571200, 
1551571200, 1551571200, 1550966400, 1550966400, 1550966400, 1550966400, 
1550966400, 1550361600, 1550361600, 1550361600, 1550361600, 1550361600, 
1549756800, 1549756800, 1549756800, 1549756800, 1549756800, 1549152000, 
1549152000, 1549152000, 1549152000, 1549152000, 1548547200, 1548547200, 
1548547200, 1548547200, 1548547200, 1547942400, 1547942400, 1547942400, 
1547942400, 1547942400, 1547337600, 1547337600, 1547337600, 1547337600, 
1547337600, 1546732800, 1546732800, 1546732800, 1546732800, 1546732800, 
1546128000, 1546128000, 1546128000, 1546128000, 1546128000, 1545523200, 
1545523200, 1545523200, 1545523200, 1545523200, 1544918400, 1544918400, 
1544918400, 1544918400, 1544918400, 1544313600, 1544313600, 1544313600, 
1544313600, 1544313600, 1543708800, 1543708800, 1543708800, 1543708800, 
1543708800, 1541894400, 1541894400, 1541894400, 1541894400, 1541894400, 
1541289600, 1541289600, 1541289600, 1541289600, 1541289600, 1540684800, 
1540684800, 1540684800, 1540684800, 1540684800, 1540080000, 1540080000, 
1540080000, 1540080000, 1540080000, 1539475200, 1539475200, 1539475200, 
1539475200, 1539475200, 1538870400, 1538870400, 1538870400, 1538870400, 
1538870400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    partidos = c("PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX", "PPopular", "PSOE", "ahorapodemos", "CiudadanosCs", 
    "VOX"), resultados = c(16.7, 33.3, 14.5, 15.3, 5.9, 21, 27.3, 
    14.2, 16, 11.3, 21.75, 25.85, 14.4, 17.9, 10.9, 20.5, 25.4, 
    13.9, 17, 11.7, 21.3, 23.9, 13.5, 20.9, 11.2, 22.25, 23.65, 
    14.85, 19.15, 10.05, 21.5, 23.2, 14.4, 23, 8.9, 19.2, 23.75, 
    16.7, 18, 8.4, 18.3, 24.1, 16.1, 18.5, 11.5, 20.6, 22.6, 
    15.5, 19.65, 10.75, 21.8, 23.5, 15.2, 22.7, 7.8, 21.4, 24.15, 
    16.15, 20.1, 8.6, 22.8, 24.4, 17.2, 19.8, 5.9, 19.7, 23.2, 
    17.65, 18.2, 10.7, 23.35, 26.4, 17.2, 20.15, 1.8, 22.3, 26.6, 
    16.6, 21.9, 3.4, 22.65, 24.95, 17.15, 21.55, 2.55, 22.6, 
    25.2, 17.7, 19.2, 5.1, 26.7, 26.8, 16.8, 19.5, 1.9, 23, 26.2, 
    18, 20.7, 0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -100L), vars = "week", indices = list(95:99, 
    90:94, 85:89, 80:84, 75:79, 70:74, 65:69, 60:64, 55:59, 50:54, 
    45:49, 40:44, 35:39, 30:34, 25:29, 20:24, 15:19, 10:14, 5:9, 
    0:4), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 5L, labels = structure(list(
    week = structure(c(1538870400, 1539475200, 1540080000, 1540684800, 
    1541289600, 1541894400, 1543708800, 1544313600, 1544918400, 
    1545523200, 1546128000, 1546732800, 1547337600, 1547942400, 
    1548547200, 1549152000, 1549756800, 1550361600, 1550966400, 
    1551571200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), vars = "week", indices = list(315:319, 310:314, 305:309, 
    275:304, 270:274, 240:269, 230:239, 195:229, 155:194, 150:154, 
    140:149, 125:139, 95:124, 90:94, 70:89, 65:69, 50:64, 30:49, 
    5:29, 0:4), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 30L, 
5L, 30L, 10L, 35L, 40L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 30L, 5L, 20L, 5L, 15L, 
20L, 25L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 40L, labels = structure(list(
    week = structure(c(1538870400, 1539475200, 1540080000, 1540684800, 
    1541289600, 1541894400, 1543708800, 1544313600, 1544918400, 
    1545523200, 1546128000, 1546732800, 1547337600, 1547942400, 
    1548547200, 1549152000, 1549756800, 1550361600, 1550966400, 
    1551571200), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L), vars = "week", indices = list(
    c(63L, 127L, 191L, 255L, 319L), c(62L, 126L, 190L, 254L, 
    318L), c(61L, 125L, 189L, 253L, 317L), c(55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
    59L, 60L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 183L, 184L, 
    185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 
    311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L), c(54L, 118L, 182L, 246L, 
    310L), c(48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 
    115L, 116L, 117L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 240L, 
    241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 
    309L), c(46L, 47L, 110L, 111L, 174L, 175L, 238L, 239L, 302L, 
    303L), c(39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 
    106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 
    173L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 295L, 296L, 
    297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L), c(31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
    36L, 37L, 38L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
    159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 223L, 224L, 
    225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 
    291L, 292L, 293L, 294L), c(30L, 94L, 158L, 222L, 286L), c(28L, 
    29L, 92L, 93L, 156L, 157L, 220L, 221L, 284L, 285L), c(25L, 
    26L, 27L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 
    281L, 282L, 283L), c(19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 83L, 84L, 
    85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 211L, 
    212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 
    280L), c(18L, 82L, 146L, 210L, 274L), c(14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 
    209L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L), c(13L, 77L, 141L, 205L, 269L
    ), c(10L, 11L, 12L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 138L, 139L, 140L, 202L, 
    203L, 204L, 266L, 267L, 268L), c(6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 70L, 71L, 
    72L, 73L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 
    262L, 263L, 264L, 265L), c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 65L, 66L, 
    67L, 68L, 69L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 193L, 194L, 
    195L, 196L, 197L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L), c(0L, 64L, 
    128L, 192L, 256L)), drop = TRUE, group_sizes = c(5L, 5L, 
5L, 30L, 5L, 30L, 10L, 35L, 40L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 30L, 5L, 20L, 
5L, 15L, 20L, 25L, 5L), biggest_group_size = 40L)))

anim <- ggplot(polls_, aes(semana, resultados, group = partidos)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = as.POSIXct("2019-03-08 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), yend = resultados), 
               linetype = 2, colour = 'grey') + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = as.POSIXct("2019-03-15 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), label = partidos),
            hjust = 0) + 
  transition_reveal(semana) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') + 
  labs(title = 'Opinion polling for the 2019 Spanish general election', 
       y = 'Estimated results', x = 'week') + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 40, 5.5, 5.5))

animate(anim, width = 900, height = 600, fps = 10, rewind = FALSE, duration = 15)
```

Here I include the animation:

[image: animation]

Comment: I've tried <end_pause>, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you include the output of `dput(polls_)` in your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are two steps to address your two problems:

1. Sort your data frame before passing it to `ggplot()`:

```
polls_ <- arrange(polls_, week)
```

2. Include `end_pause = <some positive integer>` in `animate(anim, ...)`.

Note: the column name in your sample data frame is `week`, while your code used `semana`. I'm going with the former here.

**Explanation**:

Your data frame is arranged with the latest `week` values on top, and the earliest below. This does not work well with the default parameters for `transition_reveal`.

From `?transition_reveal`:

```
transition_reveal(along, range = NULL, keep_last = TRUE, id)
```

where `keep_last` is a TRUE / FALSE value for whether the last row of the data should be kept for subsequent frames.

When the earliest `week` rows are in this position, they are scheduled to appear first due to their `week` values, & are kept visible till the end due to `keep_last = TRUE`.

When we sort rows by `week`, on the other hand, the latest `week` values get sorted to the bottom rows instead. Now `keep_last = TRUE` work in our favour, because we **want** these values to be kept for all subsequent frames--most importantly, *the* last frame, which is where `end_pause` becomes useful.

**Demonstration**:

```
library(dplyr)

anim <- polls_ %>% 
  arrange(week) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(week, resultados, group = partidos)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(aes(xend = as.POSIXct("2019-03-08 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), yend = resultados), 
               linetype = 2, colour = 'grey') + 
  geom_point(size = 2) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = as.POSIXct("2019-03-15 00:00:00", tz="UTC"), label = partidos),
            hjust = 0) + 
  transition_reveal(week) + 
  coord_cartesian(clip = 'off') + 
  labs(title = 'Opinion polling for the 2019 Spanish general election', 
       y = 'Estimated results', x = 'week') + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 40, 5.5, 5.5))

animate(anim, width = 900, height = 600, 
        end_pause = 10,
        fps = 10, rewind = FALSE, duration = 15)
```

[image: result]

Comment: I am very grateful not only for the corrected code but also for the illustrative explanation you offer.